# Editor inserting bootstrap css and we don't know why

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is an unusual one (I think).

We run a news site, and sometimes when editing posts (using the classic editor, not the new block one) we find that a paragraph in the post we are editing has somehow become wrapped in a bunch of spans containing bootstrap css classes.

i.e. the paragraph becomes this

```
<p><span style="color: var(--bs-body-color); font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family); font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size); text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align); background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);">
{CONTENT}
</span></p>`
```

When it was originally just a normal `<p>{CONTENT}</p>`.

What we've discovered so far:

- The markup seems to be added when a post is saved
- It isn't just a case of cut-and-paste - the editor can just typing into the article
- The editor doesn't have to be editing the paragraph which changes
- Searching the server for "body-font-family" doesn't return results in php or js files
- Searching the client (i.e. browser including any externally loaded files) for "body-font-family" also doesn't return any results
- Multiple editors running multiple browsers have seen this so it's not a plug-in in the browser
- It doesn't happen all the time
- We can spot no pattern between the posts and paragraphs which have these tags added

Any/all suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: Have you tried searching the theme and plugins for "span" to see if there's a filter or hook being triggered when the post is saved?

Comment: @deanWombourne, Try printing all the attached functions to the action `save_post` and `the_content`. This might give you an idea about any additional function running on either action.

 You can use this script: https://gist.github.com/helgatheviking/2d9e1208a96978b2154b

Answer (score 1):

Without checking your install it's a bit of a guessing game, but I'd say your TinyMCE editor has a bootstrap plugin installed (there are several). Perhaps the developer tried to remove it, but only removed the buttons in the editor. Any case, it might be active without you noticing, with the plugin's jquery interfering with WordPress, leading to erratic behaviour.

Also, the plugin may not be on your own server, but loaded from a cdn. Have you checked the editor page html for strings like 'bootstrap'?

---

Completely different option: some plugin is messing with your content by adding itself to the [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook. But this looks less likely to me, because I can't see why a plugin would do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. In developer tools, find if bootstrap css is added. Look in list of loaded css files. Copy the name of css.
2. Search entire wp-content for that css name to find where it is enqueued.
3. Now, when you located plugin or theme part, search within this directory for a hook [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/).
4. It is probably this hook, which is hooked to callback function, in which by using regular expressions this extra HTML is added.

Comment: But the question says the markup is being added when the post is saved, not when it's displayed. I don't think the_content is run on save.

Comment: @Rup Yes, the css is being added into the database as part of the post, not added as part of rendering.

Comment: I am unaware of plugins which would work in that way to change content in the database, and that would be bad coding practice. However, you can try following: disable all plugins and see if this code still sticks. Search the whole Wordpress directory for various terms from string, not just body-font-family, e.g. perhaps for "--bs"